# Best approach to reference site assets URLs

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have a site collection at the URL `http://sharepointdev/discussionforum/GeneralDiscussion/`, and inside the “Site Assets” folder, I defined a logo image “logo_CMYK.ico”. 
Now, inside my site collection master page, if I write the following :

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/discussionforum/GeneralDiscussion/SiteAssets/logo_CMYK.ico" />
```

The logo will show, but if I remove “/discussionforum/GeneralDiscussion” from the IconURL like so:

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/SiteAssets/logo_CMYK.ico" />
```

the icon will not be shown.

What is the best idea to define the source for my site collection assets?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the `/discussionforum/GeneralDiscussion` ?

Comment: because on the production server we might want to define new managed path or new site collection names ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use relative paths as well.  So, from a master page's position in your site hierarchy, the Site Assets folder would be at:

```
"../../SiteAssets/logo_CMYK.ico"
```

Comment: so the generated URL in this case will be "SERVERNAME/MANGE PATH NAME/SITE COLLECTION NAME/SiteAssets/logo_CMYK.ico" ?

Comment: If it is placed on a page from the root site collection, then yes.

Note that every subsite created also has its own 'Site Assets' library.  So, if I use this relative path on a subsite that is 3 levels down in the hierarchy, then it will look in that particular subsite's SiteAssets directory.

Comment: but if the subsite have 3 levels ,, then you should define "../../../SiteAssets/logo_CMYK.ico", is that right?

Comment: If you want to always link to the SiteAssets folder of the **Site Collection**, regardless of whether you are on a subsite or not, then lgauds suggestion of the ~sitecollection url token is what you should use.  If you want to always link to the SiteAssets folder of the **current site** (whether it be site collection or subsite), then the relative path solution is what you should use.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using the ~sitecollection [url token](http://sharepointgroup.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/sharepoint-url-tokens/)?
`IconUrl="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/logo_CMYK.ico"`

Comment: This does not works!

Comment: "~sitecollection" is handled as plainstring inSP2016. "IconUrl" is not renedering in the same way as scriptlink or other component inside Master page.